# How to use if-else condition in arrow function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use an `if else` condition in JavaScript using an arrow function?

Comment: Yes, there's nothing special about it. You use it exactly the same way as in an ordinary function.

Comment: Arrow functions are just a shorthand, but the body can be normal.

Comment: Did you try and get an error? Show what you tried and we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

An arrow function can simply be seen as a concise version of a regular function, except that the `return` is implied (among a few other subtle things you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)). One nice way to use an if/else is though a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). Take this regular function:

```
function(a){
    if(a < 10){
        return 'valid';
    }else{
        return 'invalid';
    }
}
```

The equivalent in an arrow function using a ternary is:

```
a => (a < 10) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
```

Comment: This answer doesn't actually use an if-statement in an arrow-function.

Comment: @SimonForsberg If you read the question more closely, you should recognise that the wording is `if-else condition`, for which a ternary perfectly fits. But if you want to be pedantic, you will notice that the mdn for ternarys also says, `This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement.`

Comment: I had an issue yesterday where I wanted to do a `if (something) doSomething()` in React-Native and do nothing otherwise, which is why this answer wasn't so helpful for me. Turns out that I *had* to return a value from the arrow-function for some reason, even though the docs said that it wasn't used. If you're wondering, it was https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#getitem

Comment: This should work with ES6 with function name:

const get = a => (a < 10 ? 'valid' : 'invalid');

Comment: the parentheses are unnecessary

Answer (score 25):

As you've probably found, the body of an arrow function without braces can only be a single expression, so if statements are not allowed.

Statements are allowed in arrow functions with braces though, like this:

```
const func = () => {
    if (...) ...
}
```

Answer (score 22):

For a single 'if' condition, you may use a shortcut syntax.

Imagine you need to execute a doThis() function only if a > 10:

```
a => a > 10 && doThis()
```

Comment: Is there a shortcut syntax for a single "if" condition and assignment? i.e. assign a value to a variable only if a > 10?

Comment: myVariable = (a >10) ? newValue : myVariable ;

Comment: I had no idea. This worked for my situation - thank you.

Comment: This is so so nice. I'm using `noop()` from RxJS, and burst out laughing at myself for this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how arrow functions operate.

```
var foo = (value) => value;
```

Is the same as:

```
var foo = (value) => {
    return value;
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
function foo(value) {
    return value;
}
```

So as you can see there is nothing special about putting if-else inside arrow functions.

Comment: Your last one should be `function foo(value) { return value; }.bind(this)`

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it that I found useful.

For this regular function,

```js
function(a){
    if(a < 10){
        return 'valid';
    }
}
```

The equivalent in an arrow function is

```js
a => {
    if(a < 10){
        return 'valid';
    }
}
```

I found this useful when doing conditional mapping of an array data in a React project. An example is below:

```js
function App(){
    const items = useFetch()
    return (
        <div>
            {items.map( (item) => {
                if (item[1]==='something'){
                    return (
                        <li>{item[2]}</li>
                    )
                }
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can use ternary operator to achive this.

```js
const myArrowFunction = (a) => {
 return a === 10 ? "a is equal to 10" : "a is not equal to 10" 
}

console.log(myArrowFunction(50))
```

This is equivalent to :

```js
const myFunction = function (a){
 if (a === 10){
 return "a is equal to 10"
 }
 return "a is not equal to 10"
}

console.log(myFunction(50))
```

**Note :**
Using this method you can chain as much expressions as you have conditions however, this is to be avoid for the sake of code readability and maintainability. Use the old `if/else` or `switch` statements instead.
Find more about ternary operator in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)