# React Native arrow functions and 'if' statements

Tags: if-statement, react-native, arrow-functions

I have just been schooled on arrow functions, and how they can aid with visibility when you start using sub-functions on   *[React Native and globally accessible objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209526/react-native-and-globally-accessible-objects?noredirect=1#comment87436338_50209526)*.

I am not sure if this is different for "if" statements, but I can't get this to work at all.  The issue:

```
myFunction() {
    console.log('Welcome Flag: ' + this.props.welcomeFlag);
    if (this.props.welcomeFlag == false) {
        this.props.dispatch(setWelcomeFlag(true));
        showMessage('Welcome back, ' + this.props.userName + '!', { duration: 3000 });
    }
}
```

In this example, the console logs the initial value of welcomeFlag, which is "false". I would then like to, if it is false, display a message to the user and set it to true. Super simple stuff.

It falls over here:

```
this.props.dispatch(setWelcomeFlag(true));
```

Because my *if* statement is not an arrow statement.

Except I can't get the arrow statement to work for *if* statements. It is working for other kinds of statements, but just not for these.

I have tried the answers listed here:

*[How to use if-else condition in arrow function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627712/how-to-use-if-else-conditon-in-arrow-function-in-javascript)*

But none of these work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You just need to bind your main function `myFunction() ` if it has not been already bound. Therefore try adding `myFunction = () => `

Comment: You just wrap the whole parent function in an arrow!?   Genius!  Thanks mate.   Please submit as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myFunction()` is a class level function. Binding anything to `this` is referring a class itself, therefore you need to bind it to access `this` property, otherwise you won't be able to access the *class level props*.

Although there are many ways to bind this as explained [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56), but the simplest one would be to use the *shorthand arrow syntax* as

```
myFunction = () =>
```

Comment: I have another follow-up if you want to try and go 3 for 3 for me?   You have been a life saver so far. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218267/react-native-arrow-functions-and-geoqueries